# Format 12.04lts and install newest version

Tags: format

I have 12.04lts installed but had troubles while upgrading it.
All graphics configurations died and I can not change them.
Dash disappeared and the applications bar vanished.

I can not upgrade or update cause I can't find the application.

I just want to fully clean the disk and install the newest version of ubuntu.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Backup all data from your existing precise machine to a disk.
2. Download latest live ISO of trusty tahr from ubuntu.com and burn it to a bootable medium (usb-drive/DVD).
3. Boot from the DVD and follow instructions.

The most "newbie-friendly" installation involves formatting the entire disk to do a clean install, so make sure you backup everything beforehand.

(However, my personal advice is - Don't DO IT! Trusty isn't ready for prime-time yet, it will take at least until September for its stability to match that of Precise.)